# Is there as significant danger to frequent close contact with a pet dog?

Tags: medical-science, zoology, mortality

An article in the National Geographic [here](https://news.nationalgeographic.com/2017/10/dogs-cats-clean-licking-bacteria-health-science/) talks of the dangers of dog licks.

On the other hand, [this NYT article states](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/11/22/well/family/dog-owners-live-longer.html) that dog owners tend to live longer and healthier than non-pet owners.

Is it dangerous to get licked frequently by a pet dog? Is it really necessary to wash your hands every time after touching a pet (as the [CDC](https://www.cdc.gov/features/healthypets/index.html) recommends) to forestall potential danger?

Comment: Can you quote the specific claim that you want evaluated? Right now, I don't totally understand what this question is asking. The National Geographic article starts with a specific example of a woman who was infected by a bacterium that apparently is commonly found in dog saliva, but not commonly found on humans. It says that she had burned her foot and the dog licked the wound.

Comment: As far as I can see, the article doesn't say that it is "dangerous" for most people to get licked by a pet dog: it says " dogs and their full-face slobber-fests [are] **usually not harmful** — as long as your immune system is strong and you don’t have any wounds on your face or mouth that would let bacteria into your bloodstream." Based on that, I don't see a contradiction between the Nat Geo article and the NYT article.

Comment: The CDC recommendation has a clear theoretical basis--hand-washing is a method that is generally used to control exposure to pathogens. Are you trying to find out if the CDC recommendations are based on any empirical studies about a potential relationship between handwashing frequency and the health of dog-owners?

Comment: @sumelic *I don't see a contradiction between the Nat Geo article and the NYT article* Especially not since the NG one is about measurable bacterial infection and the NYT one is about vague statistical (not causal) correlations.

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) The claim here is unclear.

Comment: One could argue that the presence of a dog in the household is beneficial to health, consistent with the hygiene hypothesis.

Comment: @DanielRHicks: One could make lots of arguments all day: dog walking promotes cardio exercise, petting dogs promotes certain hormones, being very sick/disabled/single/poor/living in a city/etc are confounding factors with dog ownership, dogs emit magic rays that make you healthy and happy. Without references, they are just conjectures. Without a clear claim, there's no question to answer.

Comment: @Oddthinking - The hygiene hypothesis is a real thing (at least as real as any "hypothesis" can be).  You can easily find dozens of scholarly articles on the topic.  It is believed to be a factor in polio infections, and it has been suggested as a factor in MS.  Definitely a factor in some allergies.  Basically, exposure to "benign" pathogens (such as a dog might drag in) confers immunity to similar pathogens which are less benign.

Comment: That is a far cry from showing that a dog in a household is beneficial to health.